# функция combn() как сделать комбинации с условием

Tags: r

Хочу с генерировать всевозможные комбинации вектора `р` с повторяющимися элементами длинны `N`

```
N <- 5
p <- c(rep(1,N),rep(2,N),rep(3,N),rep(4,N),rep(5,N))
cb <- combn(p, 7)
```

Но есть одно условие : комбинации не должны состоять из  одинаковых значений которые идут подряд. 
например, так можно `1,2,1,2,4,5,3`
а так нельзя `1,1,2,2,5,4,4`
 Те проще говоря  элемент `i` не должен быть равен элементу `i+1`

UPD....
Функция `combn()` генерирует все возможные комбинации с вектором `р`, как сделать так чтобы функция не генерировала такие комбинации в которых соседние значения одинаковы 
 Те проще говоря  элемент `i` не должен быть равен элементу `i+1`

вот результат работы функции где столбцы это вектора с комбинациями вектора `р`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2
[5,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2
[6,]    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     4     4
[7,]    4    4    4    5    5    5    5    5    4     4     4
```

все эти комбинации мне не нужны так как во всех есть одинаковые значения подряд.
Например возьмем первый вектор

```
      [,1] 
[1,]    1   
[2,]    1    
[3,]    1    
[4,]    2   
[5,]    2   
[6,]    4   
[7,]    4
```

здесь сначала идет три единички **подряд** потом двойки и.т.п
мне же нужно оставить только такие комбинации в которых нету одинаковых значений **подряд**

например 1,2,1,2,4,5,3   видите значения не идут **подряд** Вот только такие комбинации мне и нужно оставить, но как это сделать

Comment: напишите прямо в вопросе, что именно у вас не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
N <- 5
p <- c(rep(1,N),rep(2,N),rep(3,N),rep(4,N),rep(5,N))
p <- sample(p, 25, replace = FALSE)
cb <- combn(p, 7)

f <- function(x) {
  if (any(x[1:(length(x) - 1)] == x[2:length(x)])) return(NULL)
  x
}
cb_filtered <- do.call(cbind, apply(cb, 2, f))

# Удаляем дубли
library(data.table)
cb_filtered <- as.data.table(t(cb_filtered))
cb_filtered <- unique(cb_filtered)
```

Обратите внимание - если не перетасовать значения (`p <- sample(p, 25, replace = FALSE)`), ничего не получится.

Comment: спасибо на что то не так, в cb_filtered полно одинаковых колонок

Comment: Добавил кусочек получившейся матрицы, у меня все выглядит ок

Comment: посмотрите, первые же колонки абсолютно идентичны  [,1] [,2] так же как и [,10] [,11] и [,12] [,7]

Comment: в матрице с комбинациями не нужны комбинации дубликаты

Comment: добавил удаление дублей

Comment: Что то не то, получилось всего 7 комбинаций

Comment: Матрица была транспонирована, комбинаций по числу строк теперь.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, и особая благодарность за терпение ))